# Need clarification about Friedberg

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone clarify what he means? [image]

What does the L mean? Linear transformation??

Comment: Yes, $L_A(B)=AB$, so $L$ is the left multiplication. It is an endomorphism of $M_n(K)$. I suppose $L$ stands for "Left". This is not only "about Friedberg", but generally used.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I'm so lost in his book...

Answer (score 0):

I would hope the notation is introduced earlier in the book, but yes $L_A$ is probably the linear transformation associated with the matrix $A$.

From the corollary, it is clear that you have (separate) definitions for the invertibility of a linear transformation and for a matrix; you're supposed to show that both are simultaneously (not) invertible and furthermore, that the inverse linear transformation is exactly the linear transformation associated with the inverse matrix.

Comment: yea that's his point later on in the chapter. thanks.

Comment: I still don't understand it. Can you give an example of La? If for example A is row1: 2,3 row2: 1,5. What can La be?

Comment: The simplest example for $L_A$ would be a map $\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R^2}$ that maps a vector $\vec v = (x,y)$ to $A\vec v$ with your $A$. It can however be any map $L:V\to W$ where $V$ and $W$ are twodimensional vector spaces and for which the coordinate representations of the images of the basis vectors of $V$ with respect to the basis chosen for $W$ are exactly the columns of your $A$.

Comment: okay thanks a lot! I downloaded Axler's book and I think it's starting to make sense now.